# Deployment of Flow with Formula Entry Condition

Tags: visual-workflow, metadata, ant, entry-criteria

I have created a Record triggered flow that is after create or update.  My flow is using the new Entry Condition of "Formula Evaluates to True" as shown below and is API Version 55.

[image]

I am preparing to deploy it and reviewing the metadata log.  However, the Entry Condition is not included in the metadata log  section, or anywhere else in the metadata log.

```
...
<apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
...
<start>
    <locationX>56</locationX>
    <locationY>0</locationY>
    <connector>
        <targetReference>Assign_Branch_Id</targetReference>
    </connector>
    <object>Flosum__Manual_Step__c</object>
    <recordTriggerType>CreateAndUpdate</recordTriggerType>
    <triggerType>RecordAfterSave</triggerType>
</start>
...
```

Has anyone deployed a Flow using the new Entry Condition of "Formula Evaluates to True" option?

How will the formula entry condition be deployed if it is not in the flow metadata log?

Comment: what version of the metadata api are you using? needs to be v55.

Comment: @cropredy - I believe you are correct.  If you want to post this as the answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the Flow's API version is 55, if you are deploying using anything other than change sets, your metadata deployment tool (SFDX, ant, Workbench, Gearset, Copado, etc) needs to be running using V55 of the metadata API

Metadata API version determines what XML elements are retrievable/deployable.  As Flow formulas were added in V55, the metadata that describes the formulas needs to be at v55 or higher.

Comment: We use Flosum and they have confirmed that they have a new version in development that will address this.

Comment: In the meantime, you can use changesets or workbench if this is time critical