# Unable to retrieve Flow meatada with Formula Entry Condition

Tags: visual-workflow, metadata-api, metadata, entry-criteria

I have a Record triggered flow that is after create or update with API Version is 56.0. The flow is using the new Entry Condition of "Formula Evaluates to True".

The file structure is in metadata format and I mostly use IntelliJ with Illuminated cloud version 2. I read [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/380855/deploying-salesforce-flow-with-new-entry-criteria-option-formula-evaluates-to-t) and [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/378656/deployment-of-flow-with-formula-entry-condition) and set the apiVerions on package.xml as 56.0. I also used sfdx force:config:set apiVersion=56.0 to set the api version. But retrieving the flow I don't get the entry condition formula.

Comment: Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: are you on the latest IC2 ?

Comment: @cropredy the version is 2.1.6.9, not the latest